# Android listview adapter ...no redraw

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, android-adapter

I have the following code inside my adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.box_afisare, null);
    }

    final TextView titlu = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titlu);
       titlu.setText(Html.fromHtml(textt.get(position)));
       titlu.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,font);

        final Integer pos = position;
        titlu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                if (main_contextt.selectie.contains(id_post.get(pos)))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext," REMOVE ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    titlu.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0077CC"));
                }
                else
                {
                main_contextt.selectie.add(id_post.get(pos));

                titlu.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#404040"));

                }
            }
        });


    return convertView;
}
```

I manage to colorate the selected line or lines. But when i scroll the listview and those selected lines are no longer in view range of the phone....the background color disapear.

It disapear only if that line/lines is out of view. I think the adapter is redrawing?

What to do to remain the color set on the line/lines even after i scroll the listview?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListViews recycle their child views. So if you have 20 items in your ListView but only enough room on the screen to show 4 at a time, the ListView will only have 4 children which it will recycle to show all 20 items. When one view scrolls out of view, it is recycled for the next view coming into view. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108676/3165621) for a great explanation.

What you need to do is tie the color to some underlying data. Then you would use code like.

```
 titlu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // set data.get(pos).color
        }
    });

 titlu.titlu.setBackgroundColor(data.get(pos).color);
```

...something like that.